# Is it possible to save a picture to a floppy disk in Computercraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-computercraft

I am trying to save a picture I created in paint on to a Floppy Disk, but I don't know how. Could someone please tell how to do it, or if it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

i can confirm that with the usual paint program in computer craft you cant save images to floppy disk but you can using NPaintPro [Link Here](http://www.computercraft.info/forums2/index.php?/topic/5029-145-npaintpro/) It is actually a more advanced paint program and it is a lot of fun to use. you can even use a 3d printing turtle program to create your art out of blocks.

I have used this program to save to floppy before and to display pictures to various displays across a server through rednet.

Hope this helps.